# Maven two jar files with different properties

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I Want to generate 2 different jar files each contains different property file (Other than property file everything will be same)...Searched in the net and found that i can use 2 different profiles or execution to accomplish the same.

My question is:

1. Is it maven standard
2. If so, is it possible to generate 2 jar in single execution. (In case of profile, need to run mvn twice for different profiles)

Please share, if there is any other way to do this.

Regards

Comment: You usually try to avoid that. Why not load the property file from outside the jar? Then you need only one jar.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexibility to create many resources from one build you can achieve be using https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html